# RIA DomainService Hosting

Tags: service, dns, ria, self-hosting

i have an application, in which i have an EntityModel.
i have a DomainService which talks to this EntityModel.
i am using simple LinqToEntitiesDomainService for this application, not .svc extension files.
On Silverlight (client), i am able to get/put the data through this service.

Now my question is:
I want to see the wsdl of hosted RIA Domain service in my application.
How can i see the wsdl for this service? (as we see the wsdl for .svc service in internet explorer)

I am using VS2008 sp1 studio, .net3.5 and RIA - july ctp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your service. You can see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/29/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-wcf-wsdl-services.aspx for more details.